# addTarget parentViewController and xcode warning me up than my selector is undeclared

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

it is more curiosity than a real problem because it works. But i don't understand xcode warning.
In my application I use addChildViewController so i have a child and a parent. In my child, I had a UIButton and i wanted to event a parent's function : it works but xcode says undeclared selector parentFunction :/
I can declare this function to erase this warning but it will be dead code (bad way).
Or I can use a delegate, but why use delegate when you have a direct link.

```
[btn addTarget:self.parentViewController action:@selector(parentFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    //undeclared selector parentFunction
```

Best regards

Thx

Comment: try removing the colon after "parentFunction"

Comment: cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570907/should-i-fix-xcode-5-semantic-issue-undeclared-selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the parent view controller's .h file, and cast self.parentViewController to that class or the compiler doesn't know that method exists (since parentViewController returns a UIViewController, not your custom controller).

```
[btn addTarget:(ParentClass *)self.parentViewController action:@selector(parentFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Replace ParentClass with whatever the class name of that parent is. Also, make sure that parentFunction: is implemented in the parent class (and has the colon), and is declared in its .h file.

Comment: thx (i forgot to import the header :/ and it does not come to mind as it worked)