# How to solve "undeclared selector 'forwardGeocoderDidFail:withErrorMessage" warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7.1

How do I solve this warning?

[image]

The warning is "undeclared selector 'forwardGeocoderDidFail:withErrorMessage:'". Why am I getting this warning, and how can I solve it?

This is my code:

```
if (!handeledByBlocks && self.delegate) {
    if (!parseError && parser.statusCode == G_GEO_SUCCESS)
    {
        [self.delegate forwardGeocodingDidSucceed:self withResults:parser.results];
    }
    else if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(forwardGeocoderDidFail:withErrorMessage:)])
    {
        [self.delegate forwardGeocodingDidFail:self withErrorCode:parser.statusCode andErrorMessage:[parseError localizedDescription]];
    }        
}
```

Comment: `forwardGeocoderDidFail` method is missing.

Comment: Show your protocol definition. Also note that what you check for with `respondsToSelector` is not the same as the method you actually call. That's not good.

Comment: Check out this answer

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570907/should-i-fix-xcode-5-semantic-issue-undeclared-selector

Comment: Post the forwardGeocoderDidFail:withErrorMessage: definition. There must be something wrong with it or the respondsToSelector parameter. Maybe the name is spelled wrong or it has not been defined at all.

Comment: @PanoKatsourakis That is not a good solution. Actually fixing the problem is a much better solution.

Comment: I was just trying to help out @rmaddy. Responses like yours make me not want to participate on this site.

Comment: @PanoKatsourakis I was simply trying to point out that it's better to fix the problem than to hide it. That's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(forwardGeocoderDidFail:withErrorMessage:)]
```

with

```
[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(forwardGeocodingDidFail:withErrorCode:andErrorMessage:)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're setting as the delegate does not have a public method called: `forwardGeocoderDidFail:withErrorMessage:`

That's what's causing the warning that you want to fix.

In the line below, you're calling a method with a different signature.

`forwardGeocoderDidFail: withErrorCode: andErrorMessage:`

Make sure whatever object is your delegate actually implements the correct method, and that `respondsToSelector` actually checks the one you want.

Comment: Given that it seems the OP has no problem calling the `forwardGeocodingDidFail:withErrorCode:andErrorMessage:` method on the next line, I think it's simply a typo in the `respondsToSelector` call.

Comment: Yes, but "just a typo" doesn't explain the actual error message or why it's occurring. The mismatch in method signatures is "a typo" but why that matters & what result it has is also important.