# UICollectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAt Not Called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a stock standard `UICollectionView` in a `UIViewController` that is its delegate. However the `shouldShowMenuForItemAt` func is not called for a long press. I have added a `didSelectItemAt` func which does get called on clicking a cell to make sure the delegate is indeed wired up correctly.

I also implemented the `canPerformAction` to return true and `performAction` in the delegate along with the `canPerformAction` and `canBecomeFirstResponder` to return true in my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. None of these func's get called for a long press of a cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the solution from this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956745/6126595

Comment: @BartoszKunat I will give that a go but it seems like an anti pattern. From the documentation this method should be called by the collection view without the need for this hack.

Comment: On my machine, menu handling "just works". No need for any hack. You may be doing something that is interfering with the long press gesture recognizer.

Comment: @matt That was my expectation too. I created a sample project with just a collection view from IB and the func's mentioned above wired up which exhibits this issue.

Comment: So did your sample project work? If not, would it help you to see a working example?

Comment: @matt No the sample did not work. It wouldn't hurt to see a working example!

Comment: Okay, provided a complete working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing piece of the puzzle, which most people seem to miss, is that in order for menus to work (in a collection view or table view), the *cell* must implement the selector.

Here's a minimal example. Instruction: Make a new project using the Single View App template. Copy this code and paste it into *ViewController.swift*, so as to *replace completely* everything in that file. Run. Long press on a green square. Enjoy. (The menu item does nothing; the point is, you will *see* the menu item appear.)

```
import UIKit
class Cell : UICollectionViewCell {
    @objc func f(_ : Any) {}
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let cellid = "cellid"
    @nonobjc private let howdy = #selector(Cell.f)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.view.addSubview(cv)
        cv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellid)
    }
}
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }
    func collectionView(_ cv: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt ip: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellid, for: ip)
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let mi = UIMenuItem(title:"Howdy", action:howdy)
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [mi]
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return (action == howdy)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @matt. In addition to the cell implementing the selector as you mention, I had mistakenly overridden the `canPerformAction` in the view controller instead of implementing the one in the `UICollectionViewDelegate`!

Comment: Oh, nice catch!

Comment: It is interesting to note that the `performAction` func in the `UICollectionViewDelegate` is not called for custom menu item actions. Instead the selectors in those menu items are called directly. Rather inconvenient to perform tasks on the collection view such as deleting a cell in my case.

Comment: What I do is forward it to the delegate. The implementation in the cell is just a trampoline.